# userpoints reset for drupal 7

Tags: 7, userpoints

I need to reset userpoints for all users to zero now that the site is live. how can I do that? there used to be a userpoints_reset module for drupal 6, but it's not yet ported to drupal 7

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is D7 patch if you're savvy enough with that. I wouldn't bother with it unless you anticipate reseting frequently. An easier fix is to just truncate all the tables that store the data:

```
db_query('TRUNCATE {userpoints}');
db_query('TRUNCATE {userpoints_txn}');
db_query('TRUNCATE {userpoints_total}');
```